# Opening A Port On The iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sockets, networking, ports

I'm almost finished with an application for the iPhone and for the last part I want to open a port ( say 8080) on the iPhone/iPad/iTouch.

This part of the application allows the user to type in the IP address of their iDevice onto their web browser with :8080 and will display to them an HTML page that I've created.

I've looked through a couple of the Apple docs and I'm still not grasping the concept well enough.

Can someone lead me to an article on iPhone networking or the basics of opening a socket on the iPhone?

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of how to open a port on the iPhone for user interaction

Comment: Check **[A simple, extensible HTTP server in Cocoa](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/simple-extensible-http-server-in-cocoa.html)**.